# enforce the DirectShow to select my video device via lan

Tags: c#, directshow

I have SPE-101N encoder which is connected to my LAN .
To access this encoder and show the video I'm using this URL :

"rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.100:3000/profile2/media.smp"

I have  mission planner software, huge software for autopilot,running on my laptop.

the mission planner using the DirectShow to select the video device thus start showing the video.

this is part of there code :

```
       capGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2) new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
        var m_FilterGraph = (IFilterGraph2) new FilterGraph();

        DsDevice[] capDevices;
        capDevices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        // Add the video device
        hr = m_FilterGraph.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(capDevices[CMB_videosources.SelectedIndex].Mon, null,
            "Video input", out capFilter);
```

so when I connect any USB camera ,for example, the mission planner can recognize it as a video device , thus playing it

the problem is that I need to show the video from the SPE-101N  encoder ,via LAN, on the mission planner without altering any line of the mission planner code.

my question is : is there any free software that can convert the (TCP port :3000) ,which is the port that I'm receiving  the video frames on it, to a virtual USB device, thus the mission planner can recognize it as video device and play it ?

I tried many software but not working.

Comment: this is possible, but i doubt you can do it in c#. QEMU is doing it in C (https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/hw/usb/)

Comment: What I need is that when I open the device manager on my laptop ,i have to see a virtual usb device exists there . so the mission planner can recognize it and play it

Comment: take a look at the **dev-mtp.c** in the githublink of my first comment. i think you can use this as your base and change it to your needs.

Comment: If you are looking for software package, such question is off-topic for StackOverflow. You should rather try SuperUser or product (mission planner) specific resources.